Empty information about cipher suites on Windows
I have several Windows machines with an internal CA issuing certificates. The CA has a template for RDP connections which are auto enrolled to the machines. Windows 11 computers have no problem connecting to each other using TLS 1.2. However, When I try connecting from the Windows 11 machines to the Windows Server machines (most of them are Windows Server 2016) the connection fails with
An TLS 1.2 connection request was received from a remote client application, but none of the cipher suites supported by the client application are supported by the server. The TLS connection request has failed.

The same happens if I try to connect from Windows 10 machine to Windows 11 machine. I started looking at the enable Tls Cipher Suites and noticed something odd.
On the Windows 11 machines the information about some of the cipher suites is empty:
KeyType               : 0
Certificate           :
MaximumExchangeLength : 0
MinimumExchangeLength : 0
Exchange              :
HashLength            : 0
Hash                  :
CipherBlockLength     : 0
CipherLength          : 0
BaseCipherSuite       : 0
CipherSuite           : 0
Cipher                :
Name                  : TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Protocols             : {}

while on the server machines other suites are empty:
KeyType               : 0
Certificate           :
MaximumExchangeLength : 0
MinimumExchangeLength : 0
Exchange              :
HashLength            : 0
Hash                  :
CipherBlockLength     : 0
CipherLength          : 0
BaseCipherSuite       : 0
CipherSuite           : 0
Cipher                :
Name                  : TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Protocols             : {}

and indeed they cannot find a common one. (I suppose the situation is the same for the Windows 10 machines.)
My CA is using ECDSA_P521#Microsoft Software Key Storage Provider
with SHA384 as the Hash Algorithm.
I tried disabling and then enabling the cipher suites and changing their position, but it does not help.
So, I am wondering what can be causing this 'inactivation' of cipher suites?

SO is for programming questions
